# Filter out small grid lines from an image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering

I am trying to clear out the grids so that I can use the plot alone in a different process. I am trying to solve it using opencv. I have both actual and inverted image. I am not expert in python. Any help could be great.

Thanks in advance

Actual image

[image]

inverted image

[image]

Comment: Is the grid always the same?

Comment: Yes. Just changes the location but the pattern and size is always same.

Comment: You can use opencv sobel derivates to find horizontal and vertical lines, then filter them out. This assumes that the objects you are trying to find do not depend on horizontal and vertical lines. Can we assume that?

Comment: Yes definitely, I just need the thick segmented curve and the grid(small horizontal and vertical lines) is just noise that I am trying to filter.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol: Any possibility to filter those small lines based on thickness?

Comment: use image opening i.e. erosion followed by dilation. check this https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the opening or closing of your image (depending if you are using the normal or inverted image). Opening will first erode your image and then dilate it. This will remove small/thin objects assuming bright objects over black background.

For example, in the case of your inverted image, use

```
out = cv2.morphologyEx(src, MORPH_OPEN)
```

For more information check out [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html?highlight=open) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses a combination of filtering techniques and masks.

- Convert image to grayscale and median blur
- [Adaptive threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) image
- Perform [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Create a mask to keep the desired ROI sections
- Bitwise-and to extract plot

---

Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 15)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
erode = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
dilate = cv2.dilate(erode, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 850:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
image = 255 - image
result = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(mask, image)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

**2nd Approach**

Here's an alternative approach which is the same as the 1st approach but uses specialized horizontal and vertical kernels for filtering instead. This approach is probably more robust. Instead of using guess and check morphological transformations, we have dedicated kernels that filter out the horizontal/vertical grid lines.

```
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
```

Here's the mask result after going through each kernel

[image]
[image]

The result is pretty much the same but slightly cleaner :)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png',0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel)

cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

mask = np.ones(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 50:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
image = 255 - image
result = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(mask, image)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple solution using Imagemagick. But the same concepts can be use from OpenCV. Sorry, I am not fluent with OpenCV.

```
Threshold the image

Perform morphologic close

Use connected components processing to remove extraneous features
```

Input:

[image]

```
kernel="5x5: 0,0,0,0,0 1,1,1,1,1 1,1,1,1,1 1,1,1,1,1 0,0,0,0,0"
convert img.png -threshold 75% \
-morphology close "$kernel" \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 result.png
```

[image]

ADDITION:

Here is Python Wand code to do the same thing. Python Wand is based upon Imagemagick. It will require Wand 0.5.6 (when available) and Imagemagick 7.

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='curve.png') as img:
    krnl="5x5: 0,0,0,0,0 1,1,1,1,1 1,1,1,1,1 1,1,1,1,1 0,0,0,0,0"
    img.threshold(threshold=0.75)
    img.morphology(method='close',kernel=krnl)
    img.connected_components(connectivity=4, area_threshold=100, mean_color=True)
    img.save(filename='curve_proc.png')
```

Comment: ~@get2anc`. I have posted Python Wand code to do the same thing in an ADDITION in my answer. But see the caveats.